# CSS3 "with" selector for all classes within class? Does it exist?

Tags: css, selector

In ActionScript I got used to the `with()` selector that helped me assign attributes to one object quickly.

For CSS3 I am searching something similar, so that instead of:

```
.custom1 .redclass { background:#F00; }
.custom1 .fontbig { font-size:20px; }
.custom1 .hidden { display:none; }
```

I would only specifiy something like:

```
with(.custom1) {
    .redclass { background:#F00; }
    .fontbig { font-size:20px; }
    .hidden { display:none; }
}
```

This would improve my speed a lot and ease things, especially for targeting site specific CSS using only one CSS file. E.g. each body gets its own class and I can assign styles to each different page / body.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 does not have what you're asking for.

Your options for the kind of functionality you're asking for are found in CSS preprocessors like [LESS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LESS_%28stylesheet_language%29#Nesting) with its nesting capability.

In LESS, you could write this:

```
.custom1 {
    .redclass { background:#F00; }
    .fontbig { font-size:20px; }
    .hidden { display:none; }
}
```

which would process to this:

```
.custom1 .redclass { background:#F00; }
.custom1 .fontbig { font-size:20px; }
.custom1 .hidden { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). With it you could do something like this:

```
.custom1{
    .redclass { background:#F00; }
    .fontbig { font-size:20px; }
    .hidden { display:none; }
}
```

Then compile it with the `lessc` command into CSS. This is especially useful for styling several pages with one style sheet, because you don't have to target selectors yourself. In other words, you write:

```
body.home{
    .header{color:red;}
    .content{margin-top:20px;}
}

body.contact{
    .content{margin-top:50px;}
    h1{font-size:20px;}
}
```

and get back:

```
body.home .header{color:red;}
body.home .content{margin-top:20px;}
body.contact .content{margin-top:50px;}
body.contact  h1{font-size:20px;}
```

There's a lot more you can do with LESS, this is just the tip of the iceberg.